# Wubi froze while resizing virtual partition

Tags: wubi, resize

Ok, so I managed to figure out how to resize my disk space from 30 GB to 50 GB. Now it was copying files, but now ubuntu is completely frozen at "copying from /usr" I have no clue what to do now, I've left it alone for about 40 min. Still frozen. Please help. I don't know what I should do. I used this method : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1625371

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes a long time to copy all the files... the contents of `/usr` are typically greater than 3 GB. But if you're absolutely sure it's frozen then try to safely reboot: [Alt+SysRq R-E-I-S-U-B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key#Uses)

Turning off a Wubi can result in corruption of the virtual disk. In some cases this can be recovered, but it can result in total loss of the Wubi install.

Powering off the Wubi install is the last resort - if `REISUB` doesn't work. I'd advise checking the hard drive activity light as well - if it's active then try `REISUB` again.

Comment: I can't do anything. Everything is completely frozen.

Comment: Ok, so the hotkey worked, it rebooted. I went into windows thereafter and the new.disc file was created, at 8:08 PM (it's 9:29 now), so i don't exactly know if it's intact or corrupted now. What should i do?

Comment: You can resubmit the resize with the `--resume` option. But if you get freezes that could be cause for concern using Wubi (or was this your first freeze).

Comment: This was my first freeze. Hold on i'll try and see if it works.

Comment: Ok, it's working again, copying from /usr